# What data type to use in Rust to match Decimal in MySQL

Tags: rust, types, rust-sqlx

In MySQL, I have a table `My_Table` with a column `price decimal(20,10)`

Using sqlx, I want to query and extract the value from MySQL into my function.

Below are the relevant code

```
    let query = format!("select price from My_Table");
    let query_result = sqlx::query(&query)
        .fetch_all(&pool)
        .await
        .expect("Failed to execute query");

    for row in query_result {
        let price: Decimal = row.get("price");
    }
```

This is what I have in Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
sqlx = { version = "0.7", features = [ "runtime-tokio", "mysql", "chrono"] }
sqlx-core = "0.7.0"

sqlx-mysql = { version = "0.7.1", features = ["bigdecimal"] }

mysql = "24.0.0"

tokio = { version = "1.32.0", features = ["full"] }

chrono = { version = "0.4.10", features = ["serde"] }

bigdecimal = { version = "0.4.1", features = ["serde"] }

decimal = { version = "2.1.0", features = ["serde"] }

rust_decimal= "1.31.0" 

futures-util = "0.3.1"
```

I am getting this error

```
let price: Decimal = row.get("price");
   |                     ^^^ the trait `sqlx::Decode<'_, MySql>` is not implemented for `Decimal`
```

I've tried `use bigdecimal::BigDecimal;`, `use rust_decimal::Decimal;` as suggested [here](https://docs.rs/sqlx-mysql/0.7.1/sqlx_mysql/types/index.html) and others, none of them works.

I am able to query for columns with data types: varchar, datetime, int etc...
It is only Decimal that is giving me headaches

Comment: have you tried f64?

Comment: from your link: *"Requires the `bigdecimal` Cargo feature flag"* - did you add that feature flag?

Comment: f64 gives a similar error

Comment: This is what I have in Cargo.toml

bigdecimal = { version = "0.4.1", features = ["serde"] }

decimal = { version = "2.1.0", features = ["serde"] }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `bigdecimal` (respectively, `rust_decimal`) with `sqlx_mysql`, you need to enable the [feature flag](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html) `bigdecimal` (resp. `decimal`) of `sqlx_mysql`.

To do so, you need to change your `Cargo.toml` as follows. Assuming your entry for `sqlx_mysql` looks like

```ini
sqlx-mysql = "x.y.z"
```

you need to turn it into

```ini
sqlx-mysql = { version = "x.y.z", features = ["bigdecimal"] }
```

(or, respectively:

```ini
sqlx-mysql = { version = "x.y.z", features = ["decimal"] }
```

)

Comment: I've added `sqlx-mysql = { version = "0.7.1", features = ["bigdecimal"] }` as suggested, but I still see the same error when running

Comment: @Carlos could you edit your question to include the whole `Cargo.toml` content?

Comment: added all the dependencies in the file in the question

Comment: @Carlos with the `bigdecimal` feature, the type you get is `BigDecimal`, so you should do `let price: BigDecimal = row.get("price");`. I checked the source code and it should work.

Comment: It worked after adding bigdecimal to sqlx `sqlx = { version = "0.7", features = [ "runtime-tokio", "mysql", "chrono", "bigdecimal"] }`